# How can we serialize & deserialize a Haskell Data Struct to Bytestring?

Tags: haskell, networking, tcp

I have a TCP Server written in C++, which expects a request in following format:

```
struct Header {
   int headerField1;
   int headerField2;
}

struct Request {
   Header header;
   char[14] uniqueID;
   char[12] password;
}
```

I want to implement a client to send this request to my server in Haskell

I have tried Data.Binary.encode which doesn't do the trick.
I am more confused how can I use a arbitrary sized type in haskell. i.e. char[12];

**Haskell Code:**

```
data Header = Header 
  {
     headerField1   :: Word32
  ,  headerField2   :: Word32
  } deriving (Generic)
instance Binary Header

data Request = Request 
  {
     header         :: Header
  ,  uniqueID       :: ByteString -- I am not sure which data type to use here.
  ,  password       :: ByteString -- Same as above, as length is defined 12 bytes which is arbitrary.
  } deriving (Generic)
instance Binary Request
```

I have written a custom bytestring to data parser which works great for header as there are no arbitrary sized type

```
parseHeader = do
    Header <$> 
        getWord32le <*>
        getWord32le
```

I am looking for a Haskell way to do the serialization & deserialization of the packet structure defined to ByteString (and vice versa) along with a way to create arbitrary sized data type -- char[12]

Comment: Side comment: If the default `Binary` instances don't do what you want, it doesn't seem like a good idea to have them around at all.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I have posted the same code I was trying out. I was not sure if there was a way to do it with binary and posted the code for suggestions and improvements. I will remove it once I am sure if that's not going to work at all for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the main question first, you can parse bytestrings of a known length with `getByteString` (or `getLazyByteString`). So a binary parser for `Request` could be:

```
parseRequest :: Get Request
parseRequest =
  Request
    <$> parseHeader
    <*> getByteString 14
    <*> getByteString 12
```

If you also have a serializers, say `putRequest`, you can put it in a `Binary` instance with the parser, allowing you to use some more functions of the library for convenience (but you don't have to).

```
instance Binary Request where
  get = parseRequest
  put = putRequest
```

---

To avoid mixing up password and id, it seems a good idea to wrap them in newtypes:

```
newtype UniqueID = MkUniqueID ByteString  -- length 14
newtype Password = MkPassword ByteString  -- length 12
```

When implementing operations on those, make sure that they don't construct values of the wrong length. Then you can hide the constructors when exporting the types, so that users cannot break those invariants.

The parsers for those types are where you specify the lengths you want:

```
parseUniqueID :: Get UniqueID
parseUniqueID = MkUniqueID <$> getByteString 14

parsePassword :: Get Password
parsePassword = MkPassword <$> getByteString 12
```

Now this makes the definition of `Request` more descriptive, the only way to mix a password and an ID in Haskell code is to get the order wrong in serialization/deserialization, so this reduces the potential for mistakes elsewhere.

```
data Request = Request
  { header   :: Header
  , uniqueID :: UniqueID
  , password :: Password
  }

parseRequest :: Get Request
parseRequest =
  Request
    <$> parseHeader
    <*> parseUniqueID
    <*> parsePassword
```

Comment: What will be the implementation of putRequest?
As one can also give say less than 12 characters for password: (i.e.: a1234)

Comment: When you construct a `Password` value with a bytestring shorter than 12 you could pad it with `'\0'`. A `Password` is then directly serialized using `putByteString` because you still have the invariant that it has fixed length.